# how to build the project for intel x86 emulator instead of armeabi v7?

Tags: android, android-ndk, tensorflow

I am beginner in android,

I have successfully built the android demo with bazel. Now I am trying to work with it in Android studio.

I found this repository [here](https://github.com/miyosuda/TensorFlowAndroidDemo).

It currently works well with **armeabiv7** but **crashes with intel x86 emulator**.

But I want to build it for **intel x86 and x86_64** and I want to build it in Android studio using gradle what should I do? Please help me

I am using 
NDK 10re,
Android Studio 2.0,
UBUNTU 14.04

Answer (score 0):

as you see in this location of repo: 
https://github.com/miyosuda/TensorFlowAndroidDemo/tree/master/app/src/main/jniLibs
there are only libraries for armeabi-v7a thus it will not work on x86 emulator

---

from what is available on this repo, i see there is also jni code code for that libraries. Unfortunately there are dependencies and are also available here only for armv7 platform. To make this work it will require a lot of work, mainly searching for proper working x86 libraries/dependecies or building them by yourself.